# How to edit timespan values with an UpDown control using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, timer, timespan, numericupdown

I have a timer with a textbox displaying a Timespan value (duration).
When I stop the timer I want to edit the value of the Timespan with an UpDown control.
I want something like this:

[image]

But the above control is a datetimePicker with the Format property set to "Custom", the CustomFormat property set to "HH:mm:ss" and the ShowUpDown property to true.

So it can display only dateTime values.

I want it to display Timespan values (such as "32.23:59:59") and with the UpDown control to edit the seconds or the minutes or the hours or the days depending which is marked from the cursor.

How is that possible?

Do I have to create a custom control from scratch?

Thanks in advance.

**Edited:** After a lot of thought and experiments I found out that if the DomainUpDown Control had the methods SelectionStart and SelectionLength it would be possible to edit a TimeSpan using the DomainUpDown Control.

[I submitted such  a proposal to the Visual Studio UserVoice site. Please vote up for such a feature!](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2986711-that-domainupdown-control-has-selectionstart-and-)

Comment: If you only want a timespan, then you shouldn't be using a DateTimePicker... you're not trying to pick a date/time.

Comment: So I have to exclude the UpDown control for editing a timespan? The UpDown control is it only for DateTimePicker? Should I use two buttons (increase/decrease time)instead? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use NumericUpDownControl without using DateTimePicker, but I still suspect it wouldn't play nicely with having a timespan.

Answer (score 1):

Use the DateTimePicker, but set the following Properties

Format = Time

ShowUpDown = True

I think that's what you want.

If you want days in there, just set Format=Custom, and CustomFormat = "dd:HH:mm:ss"

Comment: If I choose format time it appears time with "am" or "pm" I want only timespan format

Comment: That's weird. My quick mockup doesn't show the am/pm. It looks just like your sample above. Try it with the custom format option I have listed above. If that is more to your liking, just look into custom formatting if you want to add months or milliseconds, etc.

Comment: The timeSpan values have format 10.59:59:59. That's what I want. I do not want dateTime format.

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry about that.  Could you have multiple NumericUpDowns (one for each element), and once timer stops have it parse the textbox out to them?  Then you could have the ValueChanged on the NumericUpDowns format the string back to the textbox.

Comment: I tried this method, but it does not allow me to set 0 days.
In my case 00:10:10 it stands for (dd: HH: mm)

Answer (score 0):

If you're dead set on using this control for a 'time span', AND you can be sure your timespan is under 24 hours,

```
ReadOnly baseDate As DateTime = New DateTime(2000, 1, 1)
Dim myTimeSpan As New TimeSpan
''// set value
DateTimePicker1.Value = baseDate.Add(myTimeSpan)
''// retrieve value
myTimeSpan = DateTimePicker1.Value.Subtract(baseDate)
```

but then you have to be able to handle what happens with timespans greater than 24 hours or negative timespans